# Magento 2 Module Install With Composer going to Vendor Folder,How to install on Server

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module

I have installed third party module with composer and we are managing code with **Git**.Since Module is installed with **composer** so it is going to Magento **Vendor** Folder.In git we are ignoring Vendor Folder.Hence this module is not tracked in Git while running git status.I am able to see modified in two files

```
"modified:   composer.json
modified:   composer.lock
"
```

My question is how I can install this module on server?Should I add and commit both modified files in git and run command composer update(but it will update whole magento) Or should I track that module in vendor folder in .gitignore file?

Please suggest me your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you would commit both the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files.

As part of your deployment process to the live environment you would need to run `composer install` - this takes the information stored in the `composer.lock` file and recreates the very same versions you had installed locally.

Comment: can you please tell me the reason why module go to Vendor directory when install using composer?

Comment: @iqbalmalik installing to vendor is the normal Composer behaviour. As to the reason for it you would need to check with the creators of Composer.